# How to understand **what does he know about it** in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "Don't make me feel worse," said Harry. He told Hagrid about the pale boy in Madam Malkin's.
>
> "—— and he said people from Muggle families shouldn't even be allowed in ——"
>
> "Yer not from a Muggle family. If he'd know who yeh were -- he's grown up knowing' yer name if his parents are wizardin' folk. You saw what everyone in the Leaky Cauldron was like when they saw yeh. Anyway, **what does he know about it**, some o' the best I ever saw were the only ones with magic in 'em in a long line o' Muggles -- look at yer mum! Look what she had fer a sister!"

I'm not sure what "**what does he know about it**" in this sentence is trying to convey. It's not a question, but with a structure of questioning. How should we understand it in this case? How should we relate it to the later context: "*some o' the best I ever saw were the only ones with magic in 'em in a long line o' Muggles...*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We call this a **[rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)**.   Grammatically, it is a question.   It's posed, however, not for the sake of getting an answer but for the sake of representing the obvious answer.

Anyway, the pale boy doesn't know enough about it.   Hagrid can think of a number of counter-examples, including Lily Evans.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also help me to understand why "the only ones" is used, to me "the ones" is just fine there.

Comment: Some of the best Hogwarts students that Hagrid ever saw were the sole magically-talented members of their families over the past several generations -- each the only one in his or her own family.  Not merely typical, exemplary or definitive, but exclusive.